# Is there a word or expression to describe when someone has learned a big word and is waiting for an opportunity to use it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word or expression to describe when someone has learned a big word and is waiting for an opportunity to use it, in conversation, or otherwise?

*Logophile* doesn't really work for me.

Comment: If I knew such a word, this would be the perfect chance to use it! (Btw there's a rule that _single-word-requests_ should have a fill-in-the-blank example sentence to show how your word would be used; it helps narrow down the required nuance. Any words that you've considered and rejected should be included too - with reasons - which would help fulfil the general research requirement for all questions on EL&U. And if you'd be happy with a phrase or an idiom instead of a single word, you might want to add _phrase-requests_ and _idiom-requests_ tags.)

Comment: Exasperatingly, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose [champing at the bit](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+champing+at+the+bit). The mouth-centered, restrained eagerness fits the bill for this interesting state.

Comment: Great.  This fits the bill pretty well , though you might want to cite [this source.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+chomping+at+the+bit)

Comment: Updated with more apropos link. Thanks @Lordology

Answer (score 0):

The only word I can think of would be **logophile**, but it may not be as specific as you'd like it.